# Change color and texture in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to change the color and image of a material but I'm not getting it, I'm using the following code:

```
elf.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('3d/caneca/e.jpg')});
```

but it did not work.
In the object I have 3 materials, I wanted to change the color of one and replace the texture of another.

Comment: _"but it did not work"_ explains nothing. You need to rework your question with more clarification and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the material of an object at run time. All you need to do is, create a material by specifying the options and assign it to the object.
For example the following code will create a 'MeshStandardMaterial' with white color and other **[properties](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material)** as specified. It will also have a texture which you have loaded. Consider '**box**' as the object on which the material should be attached.

```
var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, side: THREE.FrontSide, opacity: 0.3, transparent: true, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, map : <THE TEXTURE YOU HAVE LOADED> } );
```

As a better approach, you can load the texture using **[TextureLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/TextureLoader)**, and create a material when the texture is loaded. Following code explains that.

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

function onLoad( texture ) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map : texture, color : 0xff0000 } );
    box.material = material;
}

function onProgress( xhr ) {
    console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
}

function onError( xhr ) {
    console.error( 'An error happened' );
}

loader.load( 'assets/img/crate.png', onLoad, onProgress, onError );
```

**You can also change the color and texture of the material without creating a new material**,

to change only the color,

```
box.material.color.setHex( 0xff0000 );// will set red color for the box
```

or to change the texture,

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

function onLoad( texture ) {
    box.material.map = texture;
}

function onProgress( xhr ) {
    console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
}

function onError( xhr ) {
    console.error( 'An error happened' );
}

loader.load( 'assets/img/Dice-Blue-5.png', onLoad, onProgress, onError );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!
My other doubt is how I change the color of a specific material, since my object has 3 materials.

Comment: As I said, you can change the color of any material by material.color.setHex( <HEX CODE OF THE COLOR> );

Comment: Yeah, but, how i can get a especific material? I have 3 in the object, how i can change the color of only one?

Comment: `var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader( loadingManager );
    loader.load( '3d/caneca/final.dae', function ( collada ) {
     elf = collada.scene;
     elf.scale.x = 30; // SCALE
     elf.scale.y = 30; // SCALE
     elf.scale.z = 30; // SCALE
     elf.material.color.setHex( 0xff0000 );// will set red color for the box
   
    } );`
And I get this error: TypeError: elf.material is undefined

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I finally got it! LOL
Just do the following:
elf.children [3] .material [0] .color.setHex (0x05D131);

Comment: That's great. I couldn't help you to select a specific material without knowing about your code. Anyway you found the answer :)

Comment: Thank you very much! it helped a lot!